# Visual Studio 2017 not detecting visualizers in Documents directory

Tags: visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

Visual Studio 2017 is not detecting the visualizer I added to the Documents directory (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Visualizers).

If I put it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers it works.

How can I fix this? It works fine in the Documents directory on other machines.

**Update**

It turns out it is actually looking in the OneDrive/Documents directory! How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-installing Visual Studio fixed it. The following conditions were also met, not sure if they made a difference:

- Made sure Documents / Pictures / etc were **not** set to AutoSave to OneDrive (via OneDrive settings)
- Renamed OneDrive Documents directory before VS2017 install, then reverted.

Comment: Same issue with VS2019 and these steps resolved it. After disabling OneDrive backups on My Documents, I did not have to re-install VS, I simply hit the Repair option in the VS installer.